# IL2CPP does not work due to NDK (Unity 2019.2.0f1)

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-ndk

I desperately need to build 64-bit of my application since Google Play does not accept 32-bit apps anymore. Mono builds just fine but when I switch to IL2CPP it says it can't locate NDK. **However, NDK is automatically installed via **Unity Hub**.**

I saw similar posts regarding to NDK in previous versions of Unity but I thought this would be fixed by now with latest Unity version. I have also tried to use a different NDK but I was still getting the same error.

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

Check the Preferences dialog in the Unity Editor. It should have an option to provide a path to the Android NDK directory. There you can manually enter the path to the proper NDK installation location.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually this turned to be related to MacOS version. On my other Mac, which is newer, the same Unity version detects NDK just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the NDK path being set automatically by Unity is wrong:
Unselect 'android NDK installed with Unity' in Unity Preferences. It will show the NDK Path. At the end of the path, you need to add:

```
/android-ndk-r16b
```

Check here for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions...nable-to-locate-android-ndk/58241817#58241817